# Awkward arrow bug in CSS

Tags: html, css

Hey guys i have this carousel for which the arrows are created entirely in CSS , see **[HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/42ha78ue/)**.

Now the arrow has a slight error on hover i have applied the following code to the arrow circle:

CSS:

```
.arrow-outer-prev:hover,
.arrow-outer-prev:focus,
.arrow-outer-prev:active {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-5px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-5px);
  -o-transform: translateX(-5px);
  transform: translateX(-5px);
}
```

(The fiddle does't show the error , so i will be sharing a link).

Now on shower my intertion is to move the circle, but an error occurs and along with the circle the arrows also tilt slightly , **[SEE GIF](http://i.imgur.com/M2aCD2r.gifv)**.

The error can be seen on this link too **[HERE](http://codeandcode.co/demo/arrow-bug/)**.

The bug looks slightly different in FF and chrome. In chrome the bug looks even more awkward though. unfortunately i have not been able to reproduce this bug , nor has debugging in chrome using dev tools worked for me.

Can somebody point out to me what am i doing wrong here ? Why is are the arrows moving when the CSS is clearly for only the circle to move ?

Comment: You're not doing anything wrong. It's a performance issue with certain font faces and CSS transforms.

Comment: @BenM , i thanks , but thats a vague explanation ... in the fiddle everything works fine .. so why is it not working in the link i have provided.

Comment: Can you share a link to the Fiddle where everything works OK? Also, how are the arrow elements configured?

Comment: @BenM .. https://jsfiddle.net/42ha78ue/ the fiddle was in my question (unfortunaly i was't able to recreate the bug ! ) , hope that helps. i believe you'll see how they are configured in the fiddle.

Comment: I think you should check the overall positioning of the elements in the slider as adding `z-index:9999` (anything > 0 actually) to the `.special-promotion-slider .arrow-outer-prev, .special-promotion-slider .arrow-outer-next` in the link provided, has the same effect on the arrow with hover and since in the fiddle the arrow is isolated and z-index has no effect, I assume it has something to do with the rest of the page.